# CSV not building properly with fputcsv when one cell includes Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, excel, csv, fputcsv

I'm trying to create a csv file with php using fputcsv, where one of the cells includes javascript code.
The problem I have is that the cell which holds the javascript code includes the following characters:

> ' | " \ / ,

and this is breaking the csv file each time I load it up.  It is considering the comma in the javascript code as a separator and therefore splits the code across multiple cells.

I'm viewing the csv file in excel.

I understand that excel will encapsulate strings with double quotes, so for example the phrase:

> Joe said, "how's it going?"

would be converted to

> "Joe said, "how's it going?""

But with the javascript code, this encapsulation does not work.

Here is a strip of the offending javascript code that needs to go in the csv:

```
document.body.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/\s|\"|\'/g, "");
```

the \" in the js above is causing the problem and the comma after the g is starting a new cell.
If i do a `str_replace('\"','', ** javascript code **);` the csv generates properly. BUT I'm not allowed to alter any of the js, just escape characters

Can anyone provide any solutions to this problem? Perhaps there's a way to do a str_replace on the \" which keeps it in the js but escapes it properly for excel to view within the cell?

Many thanks

Joe

Comment: You can change your delimiter `fputcsv($fileHandle, $array, "\t");`

Comment: Unfortunately there's tabs within the js code as well...

Comment: Use a mix that would never happen in the code and use that as the separator /delimiter '||||'...can't u remove the tabs in the JS ?

Answer (score 0):

check here:

```
    $line=array();
    for($x=0;$x<=3;$x++)
    {
    $line[$x]="Sample data".$x;
    }

$line[4]= <<<EOT
document.body.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/\s|\"|\'/g, "");
EOT;

        $fp = fopen('final.csv', 'w');
            fputcsv($fp, $line);
        fclose($fp);
```

the content of final.csv:

```
"Sample data0","Sample data1","Sample data2","Sample data3","document.body.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/\s|\"|\'/g, """");"
                                                                                                                         ^^
```

using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) you could put that line in a string and insert it in the csv file.

but this isn't a solution, because it insert more quotes in csv file, but could help you to get a real solution.

More

```
echo $string."<br><br>";
$arr1 = str_split($string);

for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++) {
if($arr1[$i]=='"' and $arr1[$i+1]=='|'){ $arr1[$i]='""';}  //this will only work if "| are together
}
echo implode("", $arr1);
```

return:

```
document.body.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/\s|\"|\'/g, "");

document.body.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/\s|\""|\'/g, "");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this did not work for me either.  I'm currently trying to use preg_replace to change a \" to a \"".  This isn't working currently, do you have any ideas?  So far I've got:
$pattern = '(\\\")';
$replacement = '\\\ "';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $js_code);
which converts it to \ ""  which also isn't correct due to the space, any ideas how I can replace it with a \"" ?

Comment: Thanks Kraysak for your help so far. I've figured out the issue is probably due to the combination of fputcsv and preg_replace. I've detailed it more thoroughly in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530680/how-to-preg-replace-with-when-storing-in-a-csv-file-using-fputcsv